# Functoriality for triple product GL(2) x GL(2) x GL(2)

Tags: modular-forms, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures, l-functions

Let $f$, $g$ and $h$ be three general automorphic forms on $\operatorname{GL}(2)$.

Do we know that $L(s, f\times g\times h)$ comes from an automorphic form on $\operatorname{GL}(8)$?

Comment: The short answer is no.

Comment: The slightly longer answer is that proving such a result using traditional methods would be to check nice analytic properties for L-functions of twists, e.g. L(s, f x g x h x j) where j is an automorphic form on GL(7) (or a bit lower if you're lucky).  That's out of range for now, as far as I can tell.

Comment: By Cogdell--Piatetski-Shapiro, j automorphic on GL(n) for n up to 6 is sufficient. So, the long answer is no as well.

Comment: But suppose $f$, $g$, and $h$ are holomorphic modular forms. Is there a way to prove (potential) automorphy of $f \times g \times h$?